# Quasar dev is not a command

Tags: quasar

Using quasar cli version `2.3.0`, I get this error:

```bash
$ quasar dev
Global Quasar CLI · ⚠️ Error Unknown command dev.
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to focus more the question with only the necessary bit, and avoiding users to have to click out of SO for an image ! I also think you missed the `IMPORTANT !` bit and are outside of your project, is it possible ? (note, you could edit back entering the text directly rather than the image!)